# Existence of a functor from Ring to Grp that sends a ring to its group of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, functors

I am just starting with functors and all the examples about functors that I have seen don't gave explicit proofs that something is a functor.  I am trying to  prove that there is a functor from Ring to Grp that sends a ring $R$ to its group of units $R^*$. This exercise looks pretty tautological.

**My proof:**

In the present case $F$ is just a forgetful functor,right? so I have that for a ring $R$ and a ring homomorphism $f$, the functor $F:Ring \rightarrow Grp$ is defined by

$F(R)=R^* $  and  $ F(f)=f|_{R^*} $

i.e. the same $f$ where I just remember the property $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ restricted to the subgroup $R^*$

So to prove its existence,I guess all it suffices to do it's verify that

i) $F(id_R)=id_{F(R)}$   and

ii) $F(f\circ g)=F(f)\circ F(g)$.

Then

i) $F(id_R)=id_R|_{R^*}=id_{R^*}=id_{F(R)}$

ii) Let $f: R_1 \rightarrow R_2, g:  R_2 \rightarrow R_3$  be ring homomorphisms, the $g\circ f: R_1 \rightarrow R_3$ is a ring homomorphism and

$F(g\circ f)=(g \circ f)|_{R_1^*}=g|_{f(R_1^*)} \circ f|_{R_1^*}=(\square)$

Because $R_1^*$ is a subgroup and $f$ a ring homomorphism, $f(R_1^*)$ is subgroup of $R_2$ it remains to prove that $f(R_1^*)=R_2^*$, so that I can have:

$(\square)=g|_{R_2^*} \circ f|_{R_1^*}=F(g)\circ F(f)$.

**1 Is this the way to go? How do I complete it (specially part ii)? It's suspicious that I don't use the homo property**

**2 How does one prove in general the existence of a functor?  My guess is by giving the formula for the morphism and checking the two requisites, but am not sure if it is always possible to have a formula for $F(f)$**

Comment: One thing to prove is that $F(f)$ is in fact a group homomorphism.

Comment: The answer is not the forgetful functor.

Comment: @Randall , is that because the $F(R)$ is another set rather that $R$ itself?

Comment: @S.C. Well the question mentions explicitly that the the units form a group, so I think  is taken for granted that f is a group homomorphism isn't it? Since F(f) is just the restriction to a group. f already respected multiplication in the ring What I am missing?

Comment: The forgetful functor would send the ring $(R, +, \times)$ to the abelian group $(R, +)$.  That's not what you're doing.

Comment: But you are right, this is a straightforward exercise

Comment: @Randall Did you meant send the ring to the monoid  $(R,\cdot)$ ? That would be a forgetful functor too, right?, that forget the additive structure just like they one here, but I get now it's a not a forgetful functor because the resulting object is $R^*$ and not $R$

Comment: OK, true, but you've also changed the set, as you noted above.

Comment: @Randall  I modified part ii), I guess this was the only thing that I was missing, but I am not sure if it is true that $f(R_1^*)=R_2^*$, f a ring homomorphism.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The stuff about identities and composition in this case is trivial. The actual things you need to prove are that 1) $F(f)$ actually sends the group of units $R^{\times}$ of $R$ to the group of units $S^{\times}$ of $S$ - here you need to actually use that $f$ is a ring homomorphism, and that 2) $F(f)$ is a group homomorphism - here again you need to use that $f$ is a ring homomorphism.
2. This is an extremely general question. Mostly you build up a set of intuitions for which sorts of constructions are "obviously" functorial. For example forgetful functors, left adjoints, right adjoints, representable functors, compositions of functors. Most examples in practice can be built like this and for the others there are more details to check. The example of the group of units is a right adjoint and also representable by the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x, x^{-1}]$.

As an exercise to keep you on your toes, show that sending a ring $R$ to its set $R \setminus R^{\times}$ of *non-units* is *not* a functor (to $\text{Set}$). (More precisely, that it's not a [subfunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfunctor) of the forgetful functor.)

Comment: Regarding 2):  For $a, b$ units in $F(R)$, f a ring homo $f:R1\rightarrow R_2$:   $F(f)(ab)=f|_{R_1^*}(ab)=f(ab)=f(a)f(b)=f|_{R_1^*}(a)f|_{R_1^*}(b)=F(f)(a)F(f)(b)$. looks good?.

Comment: Regarding 1), I have to prove that $F(R_1^*)=R_2^*$ I prove the double inclusion: Let $x \in F(R_1^*)$, then x=f(a), with $a \in R_1^*$, Then there exists $a^{-1}\in R_1^*$ and $1= f(1)=f(aa^{-1})=f(a)f(a)^{-1}$, so there exists $f(a)^{-1} $ which is the inverse of $x= f(a)$, then $x \in R_2^*$. I guess I also should write it the last chain of equalities for $a^{-1}a$ ? to prove it is a two-sided inverse? And how do I show the other inclusion? It's giving me trouble.

Comment: 2) is fine. For 1), there is no double inclusion. What you have to prove is that if $f : R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism and $r \in R$ is invertible then so is $f(r)$. (This is not hard but the point is to be clear about what needs to be proven.)

Comment: Ok, then the prove is: $1=f(1)=f(rr^{-1})=f(r)f(r)^{-1} $and $1=f(1)=f(r^{-1}r)=f(r)^{-1}f(r)$, which means that $f(r)$ is invertible (no sure if I have to write both?Like, maybe it may be the case that one is true and the other no in general?).

Comment: Yes, that's fine, and you do have to write both.

Comment: In the proof of the composition condition(see my post), I guess I need to show that $f(R_1^*)=R_2^*$ (if that is true? that is that the homomorphic image of the group of units is the group of units in the codomain)  in order to have be able to argue that $g|_{f(R_1^*)} \circ f|_{R_1^*}=(\square)=g|_{R_2^*} \circ f|_{R_1^*}$. I am having a hard time trying to prove that $R_2^*\subseteq f(R_1^*)$

Comment: No, you don't need to show that, which is good because it's not true. Consider, for example, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: True OK, but then how do you justify  $g|_{f(R_1^*)}=g|_{R_2^*}$ to finish the composition proof?

Comment: Those aren't the same, so that isn't true, and again that isn't necessary for composition.

Comment: Sorry about the trivial question, but that is what I get using the definitions  $F(g\circ f)=(g \circ f)|_{R_1^*}=g|_{f(R_1^*)} \circ f|_{R_1^*}...?....g|_{R_2^*} \circ f|_{R_1^*}=F(g)\circ F(f)$ ,  otherwise the only think that could be wrong is: "$(g \circ f)|_{R_1^*}=g|_{f(R_1^*)} \circ f|_{R_1^*}$", but I don't see why, since that's the definition of composition

Comment: What is your question? Those are the same and you don't need to identify $f(R_1^{\ast})$ with $R_2^{\ast}$. Two functions are the same if they have the same domain and codomain and take the same values and that's true here.

Comment: My question is what is the correct proof of the composition. By definition of my functor, for $f: R_1 \to R_2$ , $F(f)=f|_{R_1^*}$.  So I start  with $F(g\circ f)=(g \circ f)|_{R_1^*}=$ and then I think....$=g|_{f(R_1^*)} \circ f|_{R_1^*}$.... and some how I must get to   ......$=g|_{R_2^*} \circ f|_{R_1^*}=F(g)\circ F(f)$

Comment: @some_math_guy: the domain of $g$ in the middle doesn't matter. Write out first of all what the domain and codomain of the two composites are, you'll see that they're the same. Second of all, again, what it means for two functions with the same domain and codomain to be equal is that they have the same values, and that's easy to check here too.