# Start of the proof that there is a functor Ring $\rightarrow$ Grp that sends a ring $R$ to its group of units $R^×$

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, category-theory, functors

I have to prove that there is a functor  Ring $\rightarrow$ Grp that sends a ring $R$ to its group of units $R^×$. In order to to that I would start like this:

Let $R,S,T$ be rings, $h$ a homo of rings from $R$ to $S$ and define

$F: \text {Obj}(\text {Ring)}\rightarrow \text {Obj}(\text {Grp})$ as $F(R)=R^×$  ?

and

$F: \text {Hom}_{\text { Ring} }(R,S)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\text { Grp}}(F(R),F(S))$ as $F(h)=h|_{R^×}$, meaning the ring hom $h$ restricted to the groups of units and seen as a group hom

**Is this beginning of the proof, written rigorously and correctly ?** I know I have to check that

i)- F(h) is a group hom

ii)- F maps the identity to the identity

iii)- there is compatibility with composition

**1 Can I really start off by defining $F(R)=R^×$ ? I mean can I regard it as true "by construction" or is it something to prove?. That looks like assuming part of the thesis is true. But then how can I proof that part if I can't even write a formula for $F(R)=\cdot$ ? What should I have written  instead of "define $F(R)=R^×$"?  I already know how to prove the other parts but I am struggling with this part. Actually I assumed this part to prove them**

**2 Is there something else I am missing?**

Comment: You are on the right track. You can define $F(R)=R^\times$. It is a valid definition. You are not assuming part of the thesis. Because the real question here is: how $F$ is defined on morphisms? You already know how it is defined on objects. And your idea about $F(h)$ being the restriction of $h$ to $R^\times$ indeed is correct, assuming $Ring$ category consists of unital homomorphism (which is the typical definition, but not always).

Comment: This is a correct start to the proof. The only thing is that, to properly define F in objects, you implicitly used the fact that R^x is a group for any ring R. I’d say this is ok being left implicit.

Comment: @freakish But the question says to prove that there is a functor  Ring $\rightarrow$ Grp that SENDS $R$ TO ITS GROUP OF UNITS $R^×$, so how can I start off by just declaring that it's doing that to objects, don't I need a formula? Can you elaborate on this? Does one always just give the definition on Objects every time one wants to prove that something is a functor?

Comment: @AdamZ. I can considered it as a fact from ring theory, but I am still suspicious on just declaring the image to be the group of units. I wish I had a formula as with the morphisms that I can check to be well defined.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “formula” but this is a well defined way to define a functor. The group of units is unique for a given ring. In order to check whether the definition on objects is “well defined” you should verify that R^x is a group but that is something that you are already taking for granted so that work has been done for you.

Comment: @AdamZ By formula I meant like with the morphisms: $F(g)=g|_{R^\times}$. I don't just assume F(g) is a group hom, but I still have to check it. I am just worried that I am not doing that with the objects, declaring the image $F(R)$ to be $=R^\times$ withouth proof. All I know it is a group.

Comment: @freakish. Also in this answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770263/existence-of-a-functor-from-ring-to-grp-that-sends-a-ring-to-its-group-of-units/4770306?noredirect=1#4770306   it says that I also have to prove that $F(g)$ actually sends the group of units of $R^{\times}$ of $R$ to the group of units $S^{\times}$, but why?

Comment: $F(R) = R^\times$ is a formula, just like $f(x) = x^2$ is. For $F(g)$ you want it to be morphism $F(R)\to F(S)$, i.e. it needs to send any element of $R^\times$ to $S^\times$. Does it, or does it not? We don't know, we know that $F(g)(r)$ will end up in $S$ because you restricted $g$ to $R^\times$, but $S^\times$ is smaller. Let's say you have $f(x) = x^2$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ with codomain $[0,\infty)$ and restrict domain and codomain to $[0,1)$. Does $f$ send every element of $[0,1)$ to $[0,1)$? What about if instead of $[0,1)$ we restrict domain and codomain to $[0,2)$?

Comment: Well you don’t have to assume that $R^\times$ is a group if you don’t want to. You can go through the work of proving that it is a group if you personally want to. Or you can just cite the fact that the work has been done before, which is what I’d do in your position. To clarify, a functor isn’t defined on the elements in your ring. It is a map that takes your ring as a whole and gives you a group according to some rule.

Comment: @darkside $h$ restricted to $R^\times$ is what? A function $R^\times\to S$. But it is supposed to be $R^\times\to S^\times$, because that's how functors work. For that to make sense $h$ has to map $R^\times$ to $S^\times$, which is automatic if $h$ is unital, i.e. $h(1)=1$.

Comment: @freakish   Could you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770500/how-do-i-complete-the-proof-of-the-composition-rule-for-the-functor-that-sends-a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you've been given to prove might suffer from poor wording. I would rephrase it as:

> Prove that the association $F(R)=R^\times$ can be extended to functor $F:Ring\to Gr$.

And now it is clear that the burden here is to define $F$ on morphisms, since it is already defined on objects.

Still the sentence "show that there is functor such that $F(R)=R^\times$" is fine. You can still simply define $F(R)=R^\times$ on objects and it will satisfy the requirement. Of course this is kind of trivial, its like saying "show that there is function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x^2$". Yeah, it is simply $f(x)=x^2$, it is a valid definition.

That's why we can safely assume that the intention of the author was to focus on morphisms, not on objects.

---

Now, the devil is always in details. Given a ring homomorphism $h:R\to S$, your idea to consider $h$ restricted to $R^\times$ is correct. However that's not enough. Formally $h_{|R^\times}$ is a function $R^\times\to S$. But that is not correct, our $F(h)$ is supposed to be a function $F(R)\to F(S)$, i.e. a function $R^\times \to S^\times$. So the correct definition of $F(h):R^\times\to S^\times$ is simply $F(h)(x)=h(x)$, i.e. $F(h)$ is a restriction of $h$ on both domain and range.

However, for that definition to be valid we need to know that $h(R^\times)\subseteq S^\times$. Whether this is true depends on what $Ring$ actually is. Sometimes homomorphisms between rings are defined as functions $h:R\to S$ such that $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ and $h(xy)=h(x)h(y)$. Also known as non-unital homomorphisms. Such homomorphisms in general won't satisfy $h(R^\times)\subseteq S^\times$, for example when $h(x)=0$ is constant. And such homomorphism **does not** induce a homomorphism $R^\times\to S^\times$. So you need to be careful.

This is true however if we consider $Ring$ as category with **unital** homomorphisms as morphism. A unital homomorphism additionally satisfies $h(1)=1$ condition. Now, if $x\in R^\times$ then

$$1=h(1)=h(xx^{-1})=h(x)h(x^{-1})$$
$$1=h(1)=h(x^{-1}x)=h(x^{-1})h(x)$$
which implies that $h(x)$ is invertible (with $h(x^{-1})$ as its inverse), i.e. $h(x)\in S^\times$.

Note that some authors simply define ring homomorphism as unital ring homomorphism and omit the "unital" word.