# How do I complete the proof of the composition rule for the functor that sends a ring $R$ to its group of units $R^×$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, functors

I have to prove that there is a functor  Ring $\rightarrow$ Grp that sends a ring $R$ to its group of units $R^×$. In order to to that :

Let $R,S,T$ be rings, $h$ a homo of rings from $R$ to $S$ and I define

$F: \text {Obj}(\text {Ring)}\rightarrow \text {Obj}(\text {Grp})$ as $F(R)=R^×$

and

$F: \text {Hom}_{\text { Ring} }(R,S)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\text { Grp}}(F(R),F(S))$ as $F(h)=h|_{R^×}$, meaning the ring hom $h$ restricted to the groups of units and seen as a group hom

I have already proven  that

i)- F(h) is a group hom

ii) $F$ maps $R^\times$ to $S^\times$

iii)- F maps the identity to the identity

I am missing:

iv)- there is compatibility with composition

I am struggling with iv). Keeping track of the domains of composition is making it complicated. This is my try:

I have to prove that $F(g \circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)$

where $f: R \rightarrow S$ and $g: S \rightarrow T$
For that I have to check that the domains are the same and that they map to the same elements:

**domains:**

$D=\text{dom} F(g)\circ F(f)$

$=\{x \in \text{dom}F(f) s.t. F(f)(x)\in \text{dom} F(g)\}$

$=\{x \in R^\times s.t. F(f)(x)\in S^\times\}$.....

**But how do I conclude that it is equal to** $=\text {dom}(F(g \circ f)) $? To start with what is $\text {dom}(F(g \circ f))=?$ It is for sure a subset of $F(R)=R^\times$, but I am not sure wether it is actually equal to it.

**mapping**: Provided the domains are equal,

$\forall x \in D$

$F(g \circ f)(x)=(g \circ f)|_{R^\times}(x)= (g \circ f )(x)=g(f(x))=g(f|_{R^\times}(x))=g|_{S^\times}(f|_{R^\times}(x))=F(g)(F(f)(x))=(F(g)\circ F(f))(x)$

**How do I complete this part? Is the rest OK?**

Comment: Kinda weird [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4770263) was asked in the same $24$ hours. Try to browse around

Comment: Same exercise but not the same issue with the composition domains that I am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with
$$R \xrightarrow[]{f} S \xrightarrow[]{g} T$$

morphisms. Now $F(R)=R^\times$. And so $F(f):R^\times \to S^\times$ and $F(g):S^\times\to T^\times$. Lets assume these are restrictions (which are well defined if we consider unital homomorphisms btw).

So, the situation is that we have a following sequence:

$$R^\times \xrightarrow[]{F(f)} S^\times \xrightarrow[]{F(g)} T^\times$$

which clearly shows that $F(g)\circ F(f)$ has $R^\times$ as its domain.

On the other hand, apply $F$ to $g\circ f$ morphism, which is a morphism $R\to T$. This gives us $F(g\circ f)$ which (by definition) is a morphism $R^\times\to T^\times$.

This shows that $F(g\circ f)$ and $F(g)\circ F(f)$ at least share domain and range.

Concrete formulas are also the same. Easy to check, because $F(f)(x)$ is literally defined as $f(x)$, it only has domain and range restricted. Which you've explicitely checked in your last sequence of equalities.

Comment: So, youa re saying I should't worry about what happens in the middle of the composition? Notice that in my check I used  $g(f|_{R^\times}(x))=g|_{S^\times}(f|_{R^\times}(x))$ which uses that $f|_{R^\times}(x)=F(f)(x)\in S^\times$ which is the condition defining the domain D. So if I don't use D, how can I check that?

Comment: Besides the composition can have a domain smaller than the initial set I think, because the image of the first function may not be entirely contain in the domain of the second one

Comment: @darkside the domain of composition is always equal to the domain of first morphism. The range of composition is always equal to the range of last morphism. What happens in between does not affect that. The image of $f$ has to be contained entirely in domain of $g$, otherwise the composition is invalid. More precisely the range of $f$ (which might be bigger than image) has to be equal to domain of $g$. You cannot compose morphisms without this compatibility rule, it is essential.

Comment: To be precise on my naming convention: if $f:R\to S$ then $R$ is domain of $f$, $S$ is range of $f$. The image is $f(R)$, which might be a proper subset of $S$. But that is irrelevant, the composition $g\circ f$ is well defined if and only if the domain of $g$ is equal to the range of $f$. That is one of the conditions defining any category.

Comment: To make my point that dom $(g \circ f)$ doesn't have to be equal to $ \text{dom} f$ : $g(x)=log(x), f(x)=x^3$,then  $ \text{dom} g=(0.,+\infty)$, dom $f=\mathbb R$ and $g\circ f=log (x^3) $has  $ \text{dom} g \circ f=\{x \in  \text{dom} f ; f(x)\in  \text{dom} g\}=(0, \infty) $. So neither the domain of $g \circ f$  coincides with  the domain of $f$ nor the domain of $g$ is equal to the range of $f$ , but it's a perfectly defined composition.

Comment: @darkside Sorry, I made a mistake in my previous comment. It should be "the domain of composition is the domain of the *last* morphism" and "the range of composition is the range of the *first* morphism". So its the other way around.

Comment: @darkside in your example if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=x^3$ then the composition $g\circ f$ **is invalid**.  To make it valid the range of $f$ has to be $(0,\infty)$ to match domain of $g$. And with the formula $x^3$ this is only possible if $dom(f)=(0,\infty)$ as well. So the correct definition is: $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^3$. Then $g\circ f$ is well defined and everything works as expected.

Comment: I think you are looking from wrong perspective. You take formula and try to match domain with it. This is how you learn in school, unfortunately it is wrong approach. It's the other way around. When defining a function you start with domain, then codomain (a.k.a. range) and formula goes afterwards. That way you will avoid pitfalls as above.

Comment: Yeah I knew that from school, I wonder what other things I am confident about are actually wrong, what a headache!

Comment: Browsing a bit in this site, pre algebra questions seems to use my definition of dom of the composite function... Do you have an authoritative reference where its defined that  $dom g \circ f=dom f $?

Comment: @darkside it is not a definition, it is property. Given $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ what is the composition $g\circ f$? It is a function from $X$ to $Z$ given by formula $x\mapsto g(f(x))$. So what is $X$? It is domain of both $f$ and $g\circ f$. There's nothing more to this. Did you go through a foundations of mathematics course? Or a set theory course? Or equivalent? Because this really is fundamental. And category theory it is an abstract, often difficult generalization of this.

Comment: Also people do sometimes use the school method. Because it is fast. It is not really wrong, this was an exaggeration. It is implicit, context sensitive, also misleading, informal and leads to confusion.